# Secure HTTPS not working in Magento under CloudFlare

Tags: security, magento, https, cloudflare

Here is my problem:

- I have set magento to run under SSL setting the frontend secure option on admin to Yes
- The site run under cloudflare
- I set a page rule on cloudflare (according to the support instruction) that goes:

http://fabshopper.com/*
Always uses HTTPS

- I'm using ultimo theme in magento

When I open the site in the browser it shows the HTTPS connection but most of the content is not load because the links are HTTP (including CSS, Script, images).
Ultimo theme is supposed to create link either HTTP or HTTPS according to the magento settings, but the link I'm getting are HTTP

I ran out off ideas :(

Can anyone give me an hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I go through link provided by you and found many URLs loaded from insecure server. check below few of them:

```
The page at 'https://www.fabshopper.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://www.fabshopper.com/skin/frontend/ultimo/fabshopper/images/fab_shopper.png': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

The page at 'https://www.fabshopper.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://www.fabshopper.com/media/wysiwyg/autumn-cardigans.png': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Just change the HTTP to HTTPS of all insecure urls and it will solve your problem.

Comment: That is exactly my problem! The links are put into magento through addCss using xml but they are sent like http although the backend is configured to Use Secure URLs in Frontend